# How to get DB options format without saving?

Tags: theme-development, wpdb, theme-options

Using [Unyson](https://github.com/ThemeFuse/Unyson) framework. 
I am getting  theme options form data saved to a file. Was able to do that via ajax and

```
JSON.stringify(form values in json format)
```

problem I have is that the form data before it is saved via ajax is processed and for example the option that I see in form headers ,

```
fw_options[logo_image]:368
```

is saved in DB as

```
fw_options[logo_image][attachment_id]:368
fw_options[logo_image][url]:'the image url'
```

So my saved json array does not match the DB serialized array. 
This is just one of the examples of such options being processed. So all the form data is processed right before it is saved in DB.
How can I get that processed data array ?

Yes I can push the missing indexes to my json form values before i send it to a file but I do not want to do this for all options that come "out" in extended format. And for any new options that do this I would have to keep on adding.

I guess what I am trying to do is "simulate" save and instead sending the data to DB , I need it sent to my file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned [here](https://github.com/ThemeFuse/Unyson/issues/387#issuecomment-84084032) those 2 ajax actions,
here is how you can use the second action that extracts form values in db format

1. Create an ajax action that will return the settings options

   *You can add this code to `{theme}/functions.php` or to `{theme}/inc/hooks.php`*

   ```
   function _action_ajax_fw_theme_get_settings_options() {
       wp_send_json_success(array(
           'options' => fw()->theme->get_settings_options()
       ));
   }
   add_action( 'wp_ajax_fw_theme_get_settings_options', '_action_ajax_fw_theme_get_settings_options' );
   ```
2. Open the **Theme Settings** page and run this script in console

   ```
   var dbSettingsOptions = {
       $form: jQuery('.fw-settings-form'),
       options: null,
       getOptions: function (callback) {
           if (this.options) {
               return callback(this.options);
           }

           jQuery.ajax({
               url: ajaxurl,
               type: 'POST',
               data: 'action=fw_theme_get_settings_options',
               dataType: 'json',
               success: _.bind(function (response, status, xhr) {
                   if (!response.success) {
                       alert('Ajax error');
                       return;
                   }

                   this.options = response.data.options;

                   callback(this.options);
               }, this),
               error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                   alert('Ajax error');
               }
           });
       },
       getValues: function(callback) {
           if (!this.options) {
               return this.getOptions(_.bind(function(){
                   this.getValues(callback);
               }, this));
           }

           jQuery.ajax({
               url: ajaxurl,
               type: 'POST',
               data: [
                   'action=fw_backend_options_get_values',
                   this.$form.serialize()
                       .replace(/fwf=[^\&]+\&/, ''), // remove special hidden input value to prevent form save
                   'options='+ encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(this.options))
               ].join('&'),
               dataType: 'json',
               success: _.bind(function (response, status, xhr) {
                   if (!response.success) {
                       alert('Error: '+ response.data.message);
                       return;
                   }

                   callback(response.data.values);
               }, this),
               error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                   alert(status +': '+ error.message);
               }
           });
       }
   };

   dbSettingsOptions.getValues(function(values){ console.log(values); });
   ```

Comment: thnx bud! sent email back while ago.